# Moment of a function of Gaussian random variables: $\mathbb{E}[(a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j})^{q}]$

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, moments

Let $A$ be an $m\times k$ matrix with iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries and $a_{i}$ and $a_{j}$ be its 
$i$th and $j$th columns. I would like to compute the following quantity:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[(a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j})^{q}],
\end{equation}
for $q\in\mathbb{N}$.

One can expand $a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j}$ to get
\begin{equation}
\|a_{i}\|_{2}^{2}a_{i}^{\top}a_{j}+\|a_{j}\|_{2}^{2}a_{i}^{\top}a_{j}+\sum_{t\in[k]\backslash\{i\}\cup\{j\}}(a_{i}^{\top}a_{t})(a_{j}^{\top}a_{t})
\end{equation}
 and explicitly compute the expectation for $q=1, 2$ etc. But how can I generalize for larger $q$?

Is there a general result on this? Any hints/references appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $a_{i}^{\top}AA^{\top}a_{j}$ is as you have shown a fourth order polynomial, then you can expand the terms according to the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for positive integers of $q$. With the expanded terms you can use the [table of moments for the normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) to calculate the expectation.

Edit: This answers the explicit method of computing the expectation.

Comment: That is expression is a *fourth* order polynomial in the variables, not quadratic.  Although in principle your approach will work, it would be nice to obtain some kind of simplification, because as $q$ increases beyond $1$ it leads to very lengthy, messy formulas.  This much is explicitly recognized in the question, so the hope is the answers can offer something better.

Comment: @whuber True, I have tried the computation for $q=1$ and $q=2$, and the idea is to generalize it to higher $q$